# How to preserve folders on server when deploying war file

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I am developing an application using Tomcat.  I deploy by copying in a war file and restarting the tomcat serice.  However, I have large folders full of images and other ancillary data.  My question is:  is there an alternative to including all the data in the war file for deployment?  Specifically:
1) Can folders in the app folder be "protected" during deployment of a war file so they will not be deleted?
2) Would it be bad practice to upload amended classes and jsp files piecemeal to the app folder rather than re-deploy a whole .war file each time?  If it is bad practice, why?

Comment: There are standard methods for storing application data that is not part of the deployment.  You do this by writing your code so it uses a system property (i.e. a configuration variable) to tell it where application data is to be stored outside of the application itself.

Comment: preserving folders isn't really possible and any hack would be bad practice. as jim mentioned, you could look at storing things outside the project itself. Or, you could look at splitting your application into multiple war files. put all the large images etc in a different project. But it could still be managed and deployed as a war.

Comment: My reason is this:  I am developing an application which (I hope one day) will have a lot of users.  If I store outside the document root then I need to use a Servlet to access the file system which means spawning a new java Thread and I think I should not be doing that if I want to maximise efficiency. If I store in the document root the file can be sent direct to the client by the web server (in my case nginx) which I believe is much more efficient.  Please tell me if I have a fault in my logic.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this as follows:  store data outside the document root in a folder with the right permissions, then use the "alias" statement in the web server config file.

In my case I am using nginx and my location statement is:

```
    location /MyApp/data{alias /opt/myapp/data;}
```

Then I can refer to /data within the app.